# I did an internship 6 years ago in Beijing, but due to timezone difference a Background Check company refuses to call them. How do I ask for "Proof"?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-offer, internship, background-check

I got a job offer and currently undergoing a background screen, which includes verifying past employment. So far I am good to go, but they have yet to verify a random unrelated internship I did 6 years ago.

Now the company still exists, and the simplest solution would be to call them and ask. But they only call during US working hours, and then email me informing me that no one answered(they called at 3am Beijing time and were perplexed as to why HR didn't pick up).

Another problem is since the internship is unrelated to what I do now, and the fact it was in Beijing, I have lost contact with everyone and can't seem to find anyone on LinkedIn.

So now I have to somehow get documentation from them, so how should I go about asking for documentation for an internship 6 years ago? What should I say? How do I title the email?

I'm confused.

**UPDATE:** This is the email I sent to their **info@** email

> To Whom It May Concern:
>
> My name is ________, I interned at the Beijing office back in 2010. Currently I have a job offer contingent on verification of the past 10 years of employment . Because I live in the US, the background screening agency has not been able to get in contact with your HR department in Beijing.
>
> I was hoping if I could please get some form of documentation verifying that I interned at the Beijing office in 2010 in order to complete the background screening process, I would highly appreciate it.
>
> Information for HR to look up records:
>
> Name:
>
> ________.
>
> Emails used at that time:
>
> --my university email-- and --company email--
>
> Thank you.

I haven't gotten a response yet.

**UPDATE:** Now it seems the background screen vendor has "completed" my background check and apparently they just cut it short before I could get the documented proof, which is kind of annoying because it's a multinational corporation and all they had to do is call during work hours, or call the US headquarters.

On top of that they apparently listed "unable to verify employment start and end date" of another position I held in Beijing.I gave them references to two American colleagues from that time.One of them told me on LinkedIn that they did call and confirmed I worked there, but told them that he needed to go back to the office to look it up the exact dates. The reference they called told me that he told them to call back at 5:30 when he's in the office, or the next day.

Anyways apparently they never called him back at 5:30(or the next day) when he was back in the office and able to pull up information. The background check vendor then emailed me and said the employment **cleared**. They never mentioned that they had the dates marked down as **unverified**, nor did they attempt to ever call back anyone to verify.

**Now** HR has emailed me telling me that I failed the background screen. The issue is I currently do software development, and these two jobs were completely unrelated and years back as well as located in another country(which I have since then lost contact with). Anyways, I have been running around cold calling people and companies trying to get documentation together as fast as possible.

Looking back it's stupid of me to have lost documentation for a random internship 6 years ago. I made the idiotic mistake of assume they would have some kind of international checking service to call and ask.

Comment: Where is the potential employer's  location?

Comment: It's located in the US

Comment: I live in Taiwan, the same time zone as Beijing. I have the same problem (although I am retired). Every time I asked people in US to call, they seem to not understand the time zone issue. Depending on where in US., you may have different ways to do that. West coast is the easiest. They have 15 hrs difference. East coast is hardest. You may want them to call at Bejing time 7 PM to see if  they are lucky.

Comment: About the document, ask the company in Beijing to send a letter with their company letter head may be the best way. In the letter, just state that you had worked there as intern starting from when to when. This should be easy to do.

Comment: Yeah, it's more of an issue of how to ask. It feels awkward

Comment: Then you ask the company in Beijing to send the letter. If the potential employer does not believe the letter, they may not be the company you want to work for. (I am serious here. Anyone who does not want to understand time zone will not treat your experience in Beijing seriously)

Comment: Does the company not know about the concept of timezone or are they just too arrogant and demand that "those Chinese guys" better be available when *we* want to talk?

Comment: Do the people in Beijing not have email?  Or is there something I'm missing here? (I'm a different Pete to the one asking the question here)

Comment: Might sound like an obvious solution but can they not contact the other company by email or in writing? It will take a little longer but no issues with time-zones that way.

Comment: Unless this job offer is for a PHENOMENAL amount of money, I'd keep looking.  Life is too short to work for stupid people.  And I spent too many years learning that.

Comment: @WesleyLong  I already turned down another offer, and considering how long and grueling software development interview process is, I think I will wait.

Comment: @Pete Yeah I have had background checks before and it's never been a problem. Right now I am about to call TBWA's headquarters in New York and ask if they have HR records for the subsidiary company I interned at in Beijing. It feels weird doing a background check on myself, it's like I am an employee of the 3rd party vendor tasked with verifying myself.

Comment: About your newest edit, I just can agree with Wesley Long. So much stupidity doesn't make a good workplace.

Comment: @deviantfan Except this is a third party background check company, not the company he's trying to get a job at.  Their only stupidity is hiring a background check company that simply fails people when it takes a bit of effort to get.

Comment: Two points:  Unless you're the HC's employee #1, and they've never done it before, I find it hard to believe that HR is going to dump you if two internships (not CEO positions!) are unverifiable. Do they not have a probationary period to find out about you?  Second, if HR is willing to cede their responsibility this completely to the background check vendor, is this an outfit you really want to work for?  I'm with @WesleyLong on this one.  Life is WAY too short.

Comment: After reading your updates, I am all the more convinced it is in the best interests of your health to stay away from such stupidity.

Comment: The same people who picked the background check company and accepted their report would be deciding how your paychecks and benefits get processed.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Is this question actually "unclear?"  I feel like I understand exactly what's being asked.

Answer (score 22):

In your case I would do my best to explain to them that 3 AM is not a great time to be calling, and at the same time I would talk to HR about the issue since it's the only thing holding you back. Hopefully you have at least some of this in writing which you can refer to.

With a modicum of luck HR will give them a push or if it was me, get rid of them altogether and go with a more competent company for background checks. Possibly they might even decide that this particular portion does not need to be verified and let it ride. But some can be pretty pedantic.

It's really the background check company that is responsible for making contact in a timely and professional manner, they're well paid for it. Don't let their incompetence hold you back or reflect badly on you. You already have the job offer, so HR might be willing to step in on your behalf. They want you onboard.

Answer (score 12):

> Due to timezone difference a Background Check company refuses to call them. How do I ask for “Proof”?

**Not your problem.** You provided the details of your employment and of the company. If a background check is being done, the company doing it is responsible for, you know, doing the background check. That means *they* contact your past employers to verify your employment. If they're too incompetent to call internationally and across time zones, that's entirely on them. This isn't a unique situation that you're in and any background check company worth their salt will have ways of handling this.

When it comes to background checks your involvement should, by design, be minimal. Any "proof" you provide is unreliable. You could give them any number of fake credentials, phone numbers or email addresses that you or a friend controls. Part of the background check is that there's some due diligence involved. Typically that means that the existence of the companies and managers you've specified is checked and they're contacted using publicly available info.

There *are* a number of things you can do if you wanted to get documentation of your internship yourself but that's not what you should be doing right now. You don't specify why this was suddenly dumped on you but if the background check company contacted you to ask for details "proving" your employment you can just give them their main phone number and email address (info@company.com). Anything further is too much at this instance. Of course you don't want to flat out refuse to cooperate because that's a Bad Thing To Do in a background check but you shouldn't be doing their job for them. You *should* have documents from your side of things that prove you worked there (hiring paperwork, travel or visa documents, ...) and my guess is they'll ask you for that next, but you need to tell them to do their job first. Make sure you copy the hiring manager for the position the background check is for on this communication to avoid complications.

---

Since some people aren't clear on what I mean here I'll expand on why I'm giving this advice. Note that the above was written before OP's update where he was told he "failed" the check.

The way to respond to unreasonable requests like this is to push back professionally and to the extent that you can do so without it affecting you. That was possible for the OP here by reiterating the point that the internship company is located abroad and should be contacted by phone during business hours or by mail. That's all the OP should have to do in this situation and with reasonable background check companies.

Now because, the BCC has already shown itself to be very unreasonable, OP would have to start covering his bases, at the very least getting his own documentation (that you have no excuse for not having, short of a house fire) in order in case the BCC decides to arbitrarily fail the OP over this. At *that point* it's time for the next step which is sorting things out with the hiring company.

At no point will doing any of this jeapordise OP's application *unless* the HC is *also* unreasonable or just not interested enough in the OP as a candidate.

What you don't do is let let incompetent people like this walk all over you just because you're terrified of even hearing that you "failed" a background check.

Comment: `Not your problem.` I disagree. While the fault lies in the company that is being sloppy, if finally that company issues a report stating something like "It was impossible to contact the company referenced at the phone number provided" will affect the OP, not such a company.

Comment: @SJuan76 Reread the answer. The point is that it's too much work at this point in the process and OP can and should let the background check company do their job first. As long as OP doesn't antagonise them there's no risk that he'll immediately fail the check. And "impossible to contact"? Really? All OP would have to do is say "they didn't actually call them during business hours" and the background check company would be the one losing a job. Finally, please avoid using code markup to format quotes. You can use italics and quotation marks instead.

Comment: So the company I interned at is a part of TBWA which is a part of Omnicom group, do you think if I called TBWA that I could possibly get some kind of documentation?

Comment: "Not you fault" is **not** the same as "Not your problem". This has basically already cost OP a job; I would call that a problem for him. This answer is unhelpful at best.

Comment: "the background check company would be the one losing a job" again wishful thinking. The company is probably not hurting for applicants in the same way OP needs the job.

Comment: It appears, from an edit performed after this answer, that the OP did fail the background check. It VERY MUCH is his problem now.

Comment: @teego1967 Now yes. It wasn't at the time I answered the question. Steps to take now are to explain the situation to the company. A reasonably company will check with the background check people, verify what happened and then never use that background check company again. An unreasonable company will be deaf to "complaints" and OP would be lucky to be selected out.

Comment: @teego1967 could you tone down? The answer was made before the edit, so look at it from that perspective. Also he did mention an unrelated internship so that to isnt his Problem that they check something that isnt relevant to his Profession. So I would still say this is a valid answer. Their process is broken in my opinion.

Comment: (that you have no excuse for not having, short of a house fire)
Who here has tax records or offer letters or paycheck stubs from 10-20 years ago?  I couldn't prove up employment with documents in my position of my first half-dozen jobs

Comment: @ChrisKaminski Believe or not, I keep my very first job offer letter more than three decades ago and every job offer letters ever since. I keep my tax record ever since I paid income tax(4 decades). Most of them are now stored in a USB drive.

Comment: @ChrisKaminski It was six years ago and it was an international internship. At the very least OP should have some type of email record. In this day and age I would indeed say you have no real excuse for having nothing at all. I'm aware that there are people out there who don't keep a single shred of paper or a digital archive of things they really should be keeping.  I'm also aware that they don't tend to make great office employees.

Comment: @Lilienthal, I do have many emails, as well as emails that were CC'd to both to my University email and the company domain email(which I no longer have access to). They don't seem to be interested in seeing old emails from 6 years ago, they want like a letter of recommendation or something.

Comment: @RaoulMensink, One could argue, of course, that the background check company is incompetent as is the employer for not quitting them after such an incident. Unfortunately, many large MNC's are inconsistent in stuff like this and it doesn't necessarily mean they're not worth working for. I'm just saying that passing a background check really is the OP's problem and that if something goes wrong, it is his responsibility (and in his best interests) to hustle and fix it. To classify it as "Not [the OP's] problem"  is utterly unhelpful.

Comment: @teego1967 Lets put your and my opinion about are they incompetent aside. My Problem with your comment is one: Your comment isnt reasonable. Two: Even after the edit it still isnt his Problem that the Background check aint going as is should be. Yes, it is very much his Problem that he doesnt get hired, however it isnt his Problem that People are incompetent in running the process. It is clearly helpfull because he cant Change People being incompetent, he however could Change/influence what happens after and he should Focus on that instead of pointing fingers -

Comment: and saying "They are doing it wrong", Look at yourself and not someone else EVEN if they are incompetent. As pointed out by the edit you dont have any excuse for not haveing proper documentation.

Comment: @ChrisKaminski I dont know where you live but I am legally bound to Keep atleast 5-10 year old tax records on **paper**. And this includes (year summary) paychecks ect.